# "Fragment already added" after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I keep getting this error when I rotate my device:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16250): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ImageFragment{41b67de0 #2 id=0x7f0d0054 imageFragment}
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1133)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(16250):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
      ImageFragment imageFragment = 
          (ImageFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ImageFragment.TAG); 
      if (imageFragment == null) {
        imageFragment = ImageFragment.newInstance(contentImageView, null);
      }
      FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      transaction.add(R.id.grid_container, imageFragment, ImageFragment.TAG);
      transaction.addToBackStack(null);
      transaction.commit();
```

What should I do?

Comment: Where is that code? In what method?

Comment: have you tried using replace instead of add?

Answer (score 0):

When an orientation change occurs, `Fragment` is not destroyed, it gets detached from the Activity. Activity is destroyed and re-created.

**What happens under the hood when an activity is recreated?**

> if your activity instance is destroyed and recreated, the state of
>   the layout is restored to its previous state with no code required by
>   you.

Source: [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

During this phase, your fragment gets re-attached to activity, after this  `onCreate` of Activity is called. The `findFragmentByTag` now returns you with a existing fragment, Since you are trying to add the same fragment to the container you are getting the exception.

You should add fragment only if it doesn't exist at all, Ideally your code should be like this:

```
  ImageFragment imageFragment =
               (ImageFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ImageFragment.TAG);
  if (imageFragment == null) {
       imageFragment = ImageFragment.newInstance(contentImageView, null);
       FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       transaction.add(R.id.grid_container, imageFragment, ImageFragment.TAG);
       transaction.addToBackStack(null);
       transaction.commit();
  }
```